# How to expand constant function in fourier sine series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If a function is constant, by orthogonality $$\int_{-L}^L C \cdot \sin(n\pi x/L) \, dx = C \cdot \int_{-L}^{L} \sin(n\pi x/L) \, dx=0\text{ ??}$$

Comment: What is your question? Is the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval $0$? Yes. A Fourier series for a constant function will only use cosines.

Comment: "By orthogonality" here means that it is already known that all the cosines and the constant function are orthogonal to the sines. If that wasn't your problem, you are right. The value is zero.

Comment: What is $\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^L C\,\cos(n\pi x/L)\,dx$ for $n=0$?

Comment: I want sine series only

Answer (score 5):

Extend the constant function C into odd function:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} C\, \text{              for   }  0 < x < L \\
                       -C\, \text{    for }  -L < x < 0
         \end{cases} $$

You can expand step function into sine series using Fourier series, then consider the value in $ 0 < x < L$

Comment: Can I simply set f(x)=0 for negative x?

Comment: @markov, you will get extra cos terms in Fourier series if you did that.